# Change RUN behaviour based on command line parameter in docker

Tags: docker

Can I pass parameters to a `RUN` instruction from the command line when doing `docker build`?

My image is building my application using a build system, the purpose would be to be able to select different build target from the command line. Otherwise I would need a separate Dockerfile for each desired build target which is not really maintainable.

I feel like the caching system could be in the way of this feature, although it seems quite doable.

As an example, the instruction would look like:

```
RUN bazel build $BUILDOPTS //my/app:$TARGET
```

I've looked into passing args with `--build-args` but didn't succeed with it.

Comment: did you try using environment variables ?

Comment: In `docker build -h` there doesn't seem to be any other way to pass environment variables other than `--build-args`.
I did set default `ENV BUILDOPTS=` in my script, but wasn't able to alter it with `--build-args`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `ARG` to your Dockerfile.

```
ARG BUILDOPTS
ARG TARGET
RUN bazel build $BUILDOPTS //my/app:$TARGET
```

Read more: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg